# How do I jest.mock a react component import inside another react component file

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write a jest test using the newer @testing-library/react library.
This newer testing library does not have shallow rendering, so I am trying to mock out the react sub-components my tested component uses as a workaround.

But I am running into a problem using jest.mock, I cant seem to properly mock the 'subComponent.jsx' file properly.

When I use jest.mock('subComponent.jsx', ...) inside my test.js file, it only mocks imports of subComponent.jsx inside the test.js file.  When I import subComponent.jsx from inside component.jsx, the mock in test.js no longer applies.

So How do I get an import of subComponent.jsx from inside of component.jsx mocked, without having to butcher the component.jsx file internally?

BTW, I am also naturally open to any other solutions to effectively achieving shallow rendering for @testing-library/react if anyone has good suggestions...

```
test.js:

import Component from 'component.jsx';
jest.mock('subComponent.jsx', ...doSomething);


component.jsx:

import SubComponent from 'subComponent.jsx;
[SubComponent.jsx is not mocked here!!!!]
```

Comment: `jest.mock()`(unlike `jest.doMock`) is hoisted and _should_ work as you expect. what jest version do you use? maybe a bug for some old version that has been fixed for newer version.

Comment: @skyboyer "jest": "^24.0.0","@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.1.0","@testing-library/react": "^9.1.3"

I upgraded to 24.9.0 jest now, isnt making a difference

Comment: it's not _actual_ versions. see, for range `^24.0.0` both `24.0.1` and `24.0.100` may be installed to you. Actual version can be check at `package-lock.json`.

Comment: I also know hoisting isnt making a difference tried re-ordering it and using a require on component.jsx after the mock, but did not make a difference

Comment: @skyboyer checked lock file, after upgrade it is on exactly: 24.9.0
And isnt making a difference

Comment: have not found anything searching through jest [repo's issues](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+not+mocked+sort%3Aupdated-desc+). is there a chance some code above does `unmock`?

Comment: @skyboyer No only single test file and with one test and rather simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198584/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-user2765977).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, turns out this was a casing typo on my side as pointed out by @skyboyer
Many thanks.